# Accessing a network folder with ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I need to access a network folder in

```
\\p3clfs\xyz\test.tiff
```

Then:

```
String image = @"\\p3clfs\xyz\test.tiff";
MyClass.OpenUrl(image)
```

Error: c:\inetpub\wwwroot\p3clfs\xyz\ does not exist!

How can I open the URL without "c:\inetpub\wwwroot\"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the solution was to create a virtual directory in IIS.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to open a network path (so, something based on the file system,) as a URL, your string needs to be something like this:

```
String image = @"file://p3clfs/xyz/test.tiff";
```